# Energy-momentum tensor of the Dirac field

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I'm trying to compute the energy momentum tensor for the dirac field
$$\mathcal{L}=\bar\psi(i\gamma_\mu\partial^\mu-m)\psi $$$$T^{\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial(\partial_\mu\psi)}\partial^\nu\psi-\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$$ and I'm not clear on how to treat the term in $\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$: the first term gives $i\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\partial^\nu\psi$ which is the tensor given by Peskin-Schroeder  but I don't get how to compute the term in $\eta$

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/86038/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I read it and I seem to understand that this answer is missing the mass term of the lagrangian but I still don't understand how to treat the term in $\eta^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L}$

Comment: Qmechanic  my problem is basically how to multiply $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ with $\mathcal{L}$.

Comment: Why is it a problem to multiply $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ with $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: Because I can't contract the $\mu$ indices in $\eta$ with the one in $\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu$ since they are already contracted

Comment: Do you know that a symbol a for (summed-over) repeated index is immaterial, i.e. you can change it to another symbol to avoid notational clashes?

Comment: Take note that the Dirac lagrangian is 0 for the on-shell Dirac field :  $\mathscr{L} = 0$ if Dirac's equation is satisfied : $i \, \gamma^a \, \partial_a \, \psi - m \, \psi = 0$.  Also, don't forget to add the $\bar{\psi}$ terms to your canonical energy-momentum tensor.